# a video player for mac that has adjustable A-B Loop points

Tags: video, macos-catalina, video-playback

Looking for a video player for mac that allows the "A-B Loop" or "A-B Repeat" of sections of the video.

VLC can do AB Loop for sections but the only way to adjust the AB Loop is to re-set both start and end point.

The players with adjustable start and end points that I've seen so far have both been web based:

- youtube
- jwplayer

Looking for a player for Mac.  The key feature it to be able to set a section to loop and be able to adjust the start and end point of the loop to get it precise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet an online player, it allows video and audio files on the local hard drive to be played back (besides youtube video). The a-b loop section can be fine-adjusted via the keyboard (<--/--> keys) or input fields. Loops can be saved and annotated for future sessions. And the player is open-source. *Disclaimer*: I am its author.

https://agrahn.gitlab.io/ABLoopPlayer

Answer (score -2):

I have found Audacity to work very well for looping a-b with ease! Amd it's free!

Comment: Thanks, but audacity is just an audio player, not a video player.  For just audio, I've been using this one: https://29a.ch/timestretch/#  Its nice. "TimeStretch Player" by Jonas Wagner.